# REST API is returning an empty response in Ktor

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, netty, ktor

I am using [Ktor](https://ktor.io/) in my Koltin/Java class after requiring the Netty framework.

My current WebServer.kt class looks like this:

```
fun init(serviceProperties: ServerProperties) {

    val route = Routing(serviceProperties)

    val env = applicationEngineEnvironment {
        module {
            main()
        }

        connector {
            host = route.getInternalAddress()
            port = route.getPort()
        }

        connector {
            host = route.getExternalAddress()
            port = route.getPort()
        }
    }

    embeddedServer(Netty, env)
        .start(wait = true)
}
```

My method to handle all of the requests looks like this:

```
private fun Application.main() {
    install(CORS)
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText ("Test", ContentType.Text.Plain)
        }
    }
}
```

Extra information:

```
route.getInternalAddress() // 192.168.0.18 <-- (IPV4 IP) trying to test
route.getExternalAddress() // 0.0.0.0 <-- not yet needed
route.getPort() // 8080
```

My output looks like this:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 (file:/C:/Users/Kye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-all/4.0.34.Final/e1e53fb0283cc6fbc0f3631e60f658ddebcf005/netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[19:18:46.084 INFO ] Application          | No ktor.deployment.watch patterns specified, automatic reload is not active
[19:18:46.256 INFO ] Application          | Responding at http://192.168.0.18:8080
[19:18:46.256 INFO ] Application          | Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

When I head over to `http://192.168.0.18:8080/` I get

> 192.168.0.18 didn’t send any data 
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked the response code ?

Comment: How can I check the response code? @jonathanHeindl

Comment: you can type sth like this in console
'curl -i http://192.168.0.18:8080/'

Comment: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` @jonathanHeindl

Comment: does it say which server ? but nontheless it seems to be more of a devops topic than server coding : are you on the same machine as the server ?
if no try ping 192.168.0.18 and see if you get an answer (abort with ctrl c)

Comment: I am on the server - my IPV4 address is `192.168.0.18` which apparently is the first connector host you need to set, I have tried changing the IP to `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` then going to `http://localhost:8080` but I just get an empty response, no errors etc in console. It seems that my routes are not being executed, am I doing something wrong? @jonathanHeindl

Comment: im not sure about ktor but other servers tend to prefix the paths with the project name (unless specified)so maybe try http://192.168.0.18:8080/WebServer/ oO

Comment: That would make sense, since the default HTML path would be the working directory but this didn't work either - however, I'm going to look into that idea, since it might be an issue @jonathanHeindl

Comment: According to the [routing docs](https://ktor.io/servers/features/routing.html) `get('/any/route')` should be dynamically mapped as `/` being the root URI. It is connecting the the server correctly, only, the routes are not returning anything @jonathanHeindl

Comment: I have tried to add another route, like `/test` with `call.respondText("This is a test")` but I got the Empty reply still @jonathanHeindl

Comment: can you try joining the routing block to the embedded server like here ?
https://ktor.io/quickstart/index.html   (2/3rd s down the page)

Comment: The quickstart would remove my IP configuration thus changing the default listener IP to 0.0.0.0 @jonathanHeindl

Comment: I just meant the part where with the routing try putting it directly after embedded server 

`embeddedServer(Netty, env){...paths... }.start`

Comment: Yeah, still throws empty response when i remove the env and put my routes inside the instance @jonathanHeindl

Comment: wait no dont remove the env that one seems to have worked

Comment: You can’t mix the env with the open instance, the env holds the instance config hence the module linking to it, see the docs for info @jonathanHeindl

Comment: ok different approach : how do you connect the routing method with the embeddedServer start ?